# MailChimp for WordPress: any way to display a form by identifying from its name rather than its ID?

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I want to call my form from my template but I don't want to use IDs (since my form will have different IDs on different servers). Is there a way to call a form from its name rather than its ID?

EDIT: to clarify, in my template instead of calling the form using for instance `echo do_shortcode('[mc4wp_form id="7"]');` (which won't work on another server where the same form has another ID) I'd like to call it by its name using a command of that kind: `display_mailchimp_form('android_user_signup');` where 'android_user_signup' is the name of my form. That way even if the same form has different IDs on different servers, as long as its name is the same the form will successfully be called.

Comment: Are you using the same form on multiple sites?

Comment: Nope, only on my local (dev) server and the online (production) server.

Comment: Oh I se because the DEV and the PRODUCTION will be synchronous in some ways, and you are using one DB. Yes?

Comment: Nope two different ones but one single template (updated from local to remote).

Comment: I don't think I am understanding the question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try override shortcode with your own function, in your function lookup the id by attribute you passed in like "name", then call the original function.

[updated per Shawn's request, here is a piece of code]

```
<?php 
$post = get_page_by_title( 'title', OBJECT, 'mc4wp-form' );
if ( $post ) {
    $id = $post->ID;
    echo do_shortcode('[mc4wp_form id="$id"]');
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you include a code example? As this is, this is simply a comment.